# Normalization of Histogram Data Without Base Data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, statistics, data-science

I am looking for a statistically sound way to normalize histogram data, so that the sum of each point equals 1 and passes the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for 2 samples using python.

The data that I have is the equivalent of using numpy.histogram() on the sample data, but I do not have access to the sample data.

Right now I am simply applying something like:

> norm_x = x<sub>i</sub> / sum(x)

This gives me an array that sums to 1 but fails scipi.stats.ks_2samp(x, norm_x) because the proportion of the "probabilities" are not maintained.

I have looked at using scikitlearn's scalers (MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler, Normalizer, etc...) but those appear to require the original data, rather than the array of points that I have access to.

**Edit for clarity:**

I have a pandas table that represents histogram data that is similar to:

```
Counts
+-----+-------+
| Bin | Count |
+-----+-------+
| .01 |    23 |
| .02 |    48 |
| .03 |    32 |
| .04 |    62 |
| .05 |    42 |
| .06 |    15 |
| .07 |     6 |
| .08 |     0 |
| .09 |     0 |
|  .1 |     0 |
+-----+-------+
```

I want to normalize this so that the sum of the 'Count' column is 1 and the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test shows that they come from the same distribution.

Right now I am doing something like:

```
normalized = counts.apply(lambda x: x['Count'] / x['Count'].sum())
```

This does not always produce a result that passes the KS test.

Comment: Please post some sample data and demonstrate your issue, as what exactly you ask is quite unclear.

Comment: @desertnaut I updated this with an example.

Comment: The first two arguments of [`ks_2samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) must be the original samples.  It does not make sense to pass the histogram data to `ks_2samp`.

Comment: Well damn... @WarrenWeckesser you are right. With that being the case I guess I could regenerate similar sample data from the histogram, and pass that through any of scikitlearn's scalers, then check that with ks_2samp.